# How to create a trigger with specific condition?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a ADF which need to get trigger weekdays(Mon-Fri) except month start and month end if  these 2 dates fall with in these weekdays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Schedule trigger to execute ADF pipeline in this problem.

Schedule trigger provides you the ability to specify the days and the time when the trigger will be called.

Click on Create trigger -> Type = Schedule -> Recurrence (choose between Days,Weeks, Months).